# Extremely bad performance in .Net Native compiled UWP app

Tags: .net, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, uwp, .net-native

I encounter very bad performance when I compile my UWP app with the .Net Native Toolchain enabled.

I profiled the running code (native) and it seems that methods relying on reflection (Unity IoC, Behaviors-SDK, Linq, sqlite-net) are the culprit.

I use the Default.rd.xml so far.

```
<Directives xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2013/01/metadata">
   <Application>
     <Assembly Name="*Application*" Dynamic="Required All" />
   </Application>
</Directives>
```

I have no MissingMetaDataExceptions so far. These only start as I expected when I remove the *Application* line.

Is there something I'm not seeing here? The app has very good performance without .Net Native. Does it help If I write the Default.rd.xml from scratch working through all MissingMetaDataExceptions which will come?

Comment: Did you solve it? Since I can see the same behaviour in my app...

Comment: Having the same experience, the usage of .NET native in UWP store apps has made the development experience for me much worse so far.

Comment: No success so far. I removed every trace of Behaviors which helped a little bit but it's still sluggish compared to non-Native.

Comment: @JohanFalk Check this [explanation](https://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/workitem/7722)

Comment: @kubakista Thanks for the info. This may very well be the cause. We're using MVVM Light.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [UWP Tools in version 1.3.1](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2016/04/11/whats-new-in-vs-2015-update-2-for-universal-windows-developers) did alleviate the performance impact of MvvmLight.

It was still kind of slow so I switched my IoC-container from Unity to AutoFac. That helped a bit as well but was still not good enough. In the end I had to resort to creating my ViewModels via new again without using the Resolve of the IoC-Container. Now it's very snappy. I did remove all behaviors, this could have helped but I'm not sure about this without implementing them again.